# Unable to see Visualforce page in Lightning App Builder Edit Page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience

[image: here is the screenshot]

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>



        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:detail relatedList="false"/ >
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

the above lines are the exact Visualforce Code, despite having selected the option of "Include in Salesforce Mobile & Lightning  Experience" my Visualforce page isn't visible in the Lightning App Builder's visualforce Page Name Section on the RHS, it says"no VF pages available".
Am i missing something?

Comment: It seems code does not have any problem, try to refresh your app and then see. If you are not able to see your created vf page in your app builder edit mode then also you need to refresh your page. try it out !!

Comment: nope i have tried refreshing the page like a hundred time but still the same problem "No Visualforce pages availaible"

Comment: share your screenshot please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a record page, the Visualforce page's standardController attribute must match the object's type. That means that your page must start off like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Property__c" >
```

You'll need to write a custom controller in order to load the related contact and perform the necessary logic, or resort to using the remote objects API to display and update the contact record.